# Why do I get undefined index

Tags: php, url, undefined-index

I am trying to pass a variable between two webpages via a url and using php.  I am getting the undefined index error.

I have tried multiple ways of doing this and spent the last several hours googling the problem and think the following code should work -- probably just a conceptual error.  Am not using ISSET at this point because this is a url pass and it should be set.

The following code is on the passing page:

```
<DIV>
   <ul>                                    
     <li> <a href ="bulletindisplay.php?link = Bulletins/December_24_2014.pdf" title="Christmas Eve 2014">Christmas Eve, 2014 </a>; </li>     
   </ul>  
  </DIV>
```

The following code is on bulletindisplay.php

```
   <div>        
    <?php   
       $link =  $_GET['link'];
       echo $link;
      ?> 
    </div>
```

Does anyone see my error?  Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: Remove space after link...

Answer (score 1):

Remove all spaces inside `href` attribute:

```
  <DIV>
   <ul>                                    
     <li> <a href="bulletindisplay.php?link=Bulletins/December_24_2014.pdf" title="Christmas Eve 2014">Christmas Eve, 2014 </a>; </li>     
   </ul>  
  </DIV>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the space after `link` in your URL. And you should be using `isset` because if `link` is not present in the query string you will see a PHP error.

```
1. if(isset($_GET['link'])) {
2.     $link = $_GET['link'];
3.     echo $link;
4. }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove spaces inside your link.

> bulletindisplay.php?link=Bulletins/December_24_2014.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Remove all spaces and use below code:

```
<li> <a href="bulletindisplay.php?link=Bulletins/December_24_2014.pdf" title="Christmas Eve 2014">Christmas Eve, 2014 </a>; </li>
```

and in php :

```
if(isset($_GET['link'])) {
 $link = $_GET['link'];
 echo $link;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

link = Bulletins/December_24_2014.pdf
//there is a space after link
If you print out $_GET you will get output like this

```
Array ( [link_] => Bulletins/December_24_2014.pdf )
```

So

```
$_GET['link'] !=$_GET['link_']
//$_GET['link'] is not set that's why you got the error
```